# Given campgrounds array, write a function that returns a sum and matching input string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have been given a campgrounds array and I need to write a function, countByView() with 2 parameters, (campgrounds, view). I then need to add up the total number of campgrounds with the same view, and return the matching string value for that input.

For example: `countByView(campgrounds, 'ocean') //-> 3`

Here is the given array:

```
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];
```

Here is what I have so far:

```
    function countByView(campgrounds, view) {
  let ocean = 0;
  let forest = 0;
  let desert = 0;
  
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds.view === 'ocean') {
      ocean++;
    } else if (campgrounds.view === 'forest') {
      forest++;
    } else {
      desert++;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure if I'm calling the campgrounds.view wrong or it's my counter, or everything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need to count the elements with the passed `view`. Here is a working version:

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

function countByView(campgrounds, view) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < campgrounds.length; i++) {
    if (campgrounds[i].view === view) {
      total++;
    }
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(countByView(campgrounds, 'ocean'));
```

You can also use [`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to count the matching items:

```js
let campgrounds = [
  { number: 1, view: 'ocean', partySize: 8, isReserved: false },
  { number: 5, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 12, view: 'ocean', partySize: 4, isReserved: true },
  { number: 18, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: false },
  { number: 23, view: 'forest', partySize: 4, isReserved: true }
];

function countByView(campgrounds, view) {
  return campgrounds.filter(campground => campground.view===view).length;
}

console.log(countByView(campgrounds, 'ocean'));
```

Comment: Ahhh, another case of me over complicating the problem... this was a huge help. Thank you Majed!